# How to query a Timestamptz with a Unix timestamp using Diesel?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I can easily get the system Unix millisecond timestamp, but how can I convert it into something I can query with Diesel? The table in my schema has a `Timestampz` field (timestamp with time zone) that I need to compare to the Unix timestamp.

```
use diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz;

fn main() {
    let unix_time: i64 = 123456;
    let time: Timestamptz = ???
}
```

```toml
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres"] }
```

Comment: The database can do the conversion for you. Execute this native parameterized query: `select to_timestamp($unix_time::numeric / 1000);`

Comment: Seems you can use `to_sql` with a `chrono::NaiveDateTime` https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/sql_types/struct.Timestamp.html?search=timestampz#impl-FromSql%3CTimestamp%2C%20Pg%3E

Comment: @mousetail Note that this requires the `chrono` feature for Diesel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Timestamptz` can be created from a `PgTimestamp`, `chrono::NaiveDateTime` or `chrono::DateTime` according to the [docs](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/types/sql_types/struct.Timestamptz.html#impl-From%3CT%3E).

I don't think there is a direct way to generate a timestamptz, and it's supposed to be opaque in most instances. Instead where a queries requires a Timetamptz you can pass a `NaiveDateTime` and load a `NaiveDateTime` back.

Now we use `NaiveDateTime` as it's the only one that can be created from a unix timestamp. `DateTime` requires an explicit timezone and can be generated from a `NaiveDateTime`.

```rust
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;

fn main() {
    let conn = get_connection();
    let ndt = NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(0, 42_000_000);
    let (id, date) = users
        // assume a "created" column being a Timestamptz
        // you can just pass a NaiveDateTime.
       .filter(created.gt(ndt)) 
       .select((user_id, created))
       // We load back a NaiveDateTime and never deal with Timestamptz directly.
       .first::<(u64, NaiveDateTime)>(&conn)
       .expect("query failed");
}
```